# JQuery Autocomplete not working thougth values required are retrieved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have following codes to implement an autocomplete for a form field

```
 $( "#manager" ).change(function() {              
     var rows;
     var manager = $(this).val();
     var grouplist = $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>groups/getgrouplist/?"+"manager_name="+manager); 
     $( "#groups" ).autocomplete({ source: grouplist  });               
});
```

This is post response.

```
[{"personnel_name":"nab_group_1_1"},{"personnel_name":"nab_group_1_2"},{"personnel_name":"nab_group_2_1"}]
```

obiviously its getting required values and is working.
But autoocmplete is not displaying any values.
I have put an alert on grouplist and it display object object.
Can someone please suggest me how i can fix this and whats wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url();?>groups/getgrouplist/?"+"manager_name="+manager,function(response){
    var grouplist = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    $( "#groups" ).autocomplete({ source: grouplist  }); 
});
```

your autcomplete should be like this

**EDITED CODE**

```
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>groups/getgrouplist/?"+"manager_name="+manager,function(response){
        var grouplist = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var new_data_source = $.map( grouplist, function( item ) {
            return {
                    label: item.nab_group_1_1,
                    value: item.personnel_name
            }
        });
        $( "#groups" ).autocomplete({ source: new_data_source  }); 
    });
```

json should be like `[{"id":"your_id","label":"your_label"}]`

while your json is different so you have to create json on success

Comment: no this is not working , 
I am getting no error message in firebug either.
But auto complete is not generating any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check what `autocomplete` consumes. I think your object is being cast as a string hence `Object Object`. If you are passing JSON to autocomplete then ensure your backend gives JSON as a response.

Comment: Actually i have an autocomplete prior to this autocomplete.I cam using codeigniter and  first autocomplete work well , however in the second autocomplete i have to pass selection from first autocomplete and based on that generate a json for second autocomplete and this is where i am failing to rig it properly.
maybe i am not fully aware of the working of jquery autocomplete.I can manage to return proper json formatted response as mentioned in my first post. 
So basically what i am looking for is a way to implement this second autocomplete based on the selection in first autocompelte.

Comment: Could you please post some code how you achieve this: **pass selection from first autocomplete and based on that generate a json for second autocomplete**